# regex that captures optional property in style attribute

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have the following 2 strings:

```
<span id="1-1" role="presentation" dir="ltr" style="left: 72px; top: 87.8641px; font-size: 11px; font-family: sans-serif; transform: scaleX(0.999349);">&lt;span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;</span>
```

```
<span id="1-2" role="presentation" dir="ltr" style="left: 72px; top: 102.41px; font-size: 11px; font-family: sans-serif;">&lt;div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;</span>
```

I have a regex that captures the `left` and `top` values in the style attribute.
However, there is also a transform property that is optional, and I'd like to capture it if it exists.

Here's what I came up with:

```
<span id="1-[1|2]".*?left:\s(.*?)px.*?top:\s(.*?)px.+?(transform:\sscaleX\((.*)\))?.+?(?=">)
```

However, the value inside of `scaleX(...)` is not being captured.
Any thoughts on what to do?

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML. Use a DOM parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your HTML is valid, it's better to use a DOMParser to process it. For your sample data, you can easily return the 3 style values of interest:

```js
const lines = ['<span id="1-1" role="presentation" dir="ltr" style="left: 72px; top: 87.8641px; font-size: 11px; font-family: sans-serif; transform: scaleX(0.999349);">&lt;span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;</span>',
  '<span id="1-2" role="presentation" dir="ltr" style="left: 72px; top: 102.41px; font-size: 11px; font-family: sans-serif;">&lt;div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;</span>'
]

parser = new DOMParser();
styles = lines.map(l => {
  s = parser.parseFromString(l, 'text/html').body.firstChild.style;
  return { "left": s.left, "top": s.top, "transform": s.transform };
});
console.log(styles);
```